# How can I convert a string into datetime in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

How can I convert dates like "Jun 17 2009, 03:37 pm ET" into a `DateTime` variable using C#?

I have tried `DateTime.ParseExact` but I haven't figured out the correct format to use.

Comment: I usually use Chris Sell's Format Designer or the immediate window when trying to work these things out-http://sellsbrothers.com/tools/#FormatDesigner

Answer (score 7):

```
 // String to DateTime
 String MyString;
 MyString = "1999-09-01 21:34 PM";
 //MyString = "1999-09-01 21:34 p.m.";  //Depends on your regional settings

 DateTime MyDateTime;
 MyDateTime = new DateTime();
 MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt", null);
```

Source: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/String2DateTime.aspx

Modified to fit your date format:

```
 // String to DateTime
 String MyString;
 MyString = "Jun 17 2009, 03:37 pm";

 DateTime MyDateTime;
 MyDateTime = new DateTime();
 MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString, "MMM dd YYYY, HH:mm tt", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `DateTime.Parse()`? I ususally find that it is not necessary to specify the format unless there is some abiguity between what number is the month and what number is the day.