# Convert a string to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert a string into datetime in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009457/how-can-i-convert-a-string-into-datetime-in-net)

I have a string in the following format "15/03/2046". how can convert this string to a DateTime object?

My problem is when I do Convert.ToDateTime("15/03/2046") I get an exception.
when I do Convert.ToDateTime("03/03/2046") every thing works fine.
so I guess that I have to specify the format somehow while converting....

Comment: Just look at the list of related questions. Or you know.. search.

Answer (score 1):

[`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fw7727c.aspx) or its sister method [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee1y0t7.aspx).

Comment: DateTime.TryParse, DateTime.TryParseExact

Comment: Or DateTime.TryParse, which is always good if there's a chance the string your parsing is malformed or null.

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya.aspx) may be helpful too, if your date-format changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact` to specify the format of the input string:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(
                 "15/03/2046",
                 "dd/MM/YYYY",
                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

More generic code, using extension method, and default value in case if it can't parse date

```
void Main()
{
    var dt = "15/03/2046";

    dt.ToDateTime("fr-FR", DateTime.Now).Dump();
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static DateTime ToDateTime(this string dateTime, string culture, DateTime defaultValue)
    {
        DateTime dt;

        if (DateTime.TryParse(dateTime,  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture), System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
            return dt;
        else
            return defaultValue;
    }
}
```