# Populating DateTime object with this string 03-06-2012 08:00 am

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-parsing

How to populate C# DateTime object from this "03-06-2012 08:00 am" string.

I'm trying some code of follwoing type:

```
DateTime lectureTime  = DateTime.Parse("03-06-2012 08:00 am");
```

I am using jQuery based this http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ plugin to generate date time.

Update --

So many answers below and lot of stuff to clear basics for this small issue
From the below snapshot u can see what I tried and what i received during debugging in visual studio
[image]

Comment: Is that 3rd June or  6th March?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx). Something like

```
DateTime lectureTime  = DateTime.ParseExact("03-06-2012 08:00 am", "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1009466/1103571) answer uses `ParseExact` for a `DateTime` string similar to the one in the question.

Answer (score 3):

```
string lectureTime = "03-06-2012 08:00 am";
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(lectureTime , "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

- dd: days [00-31]
- MM: months [00-12]
- yyyy: years [0000-9999]
- '-': these are separated with a dash
- hh: hours [00-12]
- mm: minutes[00-60]
- tt: time [am, pm] (case insensitive)

Comment: I suspect it should be `hh` rather than `HH` - you'd rarely specify a 24 hour clock *and* an AM/PM designator.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the correct culture, your code works without modification. But you may be using a different date formatting from the program that generated the string.

I'd recommend always specifying a `CultureInfo` when:

- Parsing a `DateTime` generated by another system.
- Outputting a `DateTime` that will be parsed by another system (not just shown to your user).

Try this:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-GB"); // Or something else?
DateTime lectureTime  = DateTime.Parse("03-06-2012 08:00 am", cultureInfo);
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/jmaBl)

**Difference between `DateTime.Parse` and `DateTime.ParseExact`**

If you want .NET to make its best effort at parsing the string then use `DateTime.Parse`. It can handle a wide variety of common formats.

If you know in advance exactly how the dates should be formatted, and you want to reject anything that differs from this format (even if it could be parsed correctly and without ambiguity) then use `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Comment: in this demo it replaced - with / in output, will the generated output string format will be recognized by sql datetime datatype?

Comment: Actually, this answer is incorrect. `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` internally assumes the U.S. date format (`MM/dd/yyyy`), so it will parse the given string as 6th March, not 3rd June (as required by the OP).

Comment: @Douglas: It shoudl work if the culture is specified correctly. Maybe it's an Indian format, since the OP is from India?

Comment: Yes. Practically all European cultures use `dd/MM/yyyy` (only the U.S. uses the middle-endian format). I’ve never seen it used with `-` as the date separator though.

Comment: @Douglas if you use invariant you should specify which culture it is in the project, even if you are using the default. Anythng else is an invitation to to the ambiguity you noticed.

Comment: @MarkByers: AFAIK, Italy uses either `/` or `.`. But some regions of India do seem to use `-`.

Comment: @Douglas: eastern europe uses -